# External hard drive can't delete/write files on a specific PC

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I can't delete/write files on/to my external hard drive on one of my PCs.

I have two PCs with Windows 10 installed. On one I can write and delete files on my EHD, but on the other I can't. I have searched the internet for hours and tried different suggestions but I still haven't found a fix. At first I thought it was a faulty drive but I can easily write and delete files with no problem on my other PC.

Here are a list of things that I tried in no particular order:

- Restart the PC/Shutdown then boot the PC.
- Tried to remove readonly attribute using diskpart. Both the disk and the volume has the Read-Only attribute as "No" when I checked their details.
- Disabled BitLocker service because the following message kept popping up.
  [BitLocker message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EkHq.jpg)
- Tinkered with the registry. Added the following key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies and set WriteProtect to 0 for both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE AND HKEY_CURRENT_USER. The StorageDevicePolicies key wasn't there in the first place for both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE AND HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Rebooted after even though it shouldn't matter.
- Tried checking disk errors using CHKDSK on both the properties explorer UI and command line but couldn't because it would throw a "The disk is write protected" message.
- Tried different usb ports, front and back.

Other info that may be of use to those who would help out:

- My drive is a WD My Passport 1TB EHD
- File format is exFAT
- The drive is not full
- I can copy/read files from the drive
- Works with my other PC

Comment: The Passport drives get their power over USB. Could there be an issue with the USB port? Try running the drive through a **powered** hub.

Comment: Sounds like your other computer doesn't have permission to write to the drive.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't think it's a power draw issue, unless all of my 10 ports have power issues. I forgot to mention that I was able to use the drive before on this computer without any issues.

Comment: @Keltari where would I need to check that?